# Raster memory usage in R

Tags: raster, r

I am working with raster/brick data in R and running into memory issues. I am basically trying to use raster objects to perform some simple agent-based modeling, but the objects keep increasing in size for reasons I can't understand.

Below is some code that demonstrates what I am talking about.

```
#### Test memory ###
library(pryr)
library(raster)

br = brick()
for(i in 1:25){
  r1 <- raster(nrow = 100,ncol = 100)
  r1[] <-rbinom(length(r1),1,.5)
  br = addLayer(br,r1)
}
out = NULL
for (i in 1:nlayers(br)) {
  br[[i]][] = 0
  print(object_size(br))
  out[i] = object_size(br)
}

out = cbind(1:25,out)
plot(out[,1],out[,2])
lm(out[,2] ~ out[,1])
```

To me (limited understanding of R memory usage), the object size shouldn't change. I am simply converting 1s to 0s.

Can anyone help me understand this and find a workaround?

Comment: all, I can now see that memory usage doesn't change if runif() is used to add values to the matrix. It must be that the command br[[i]][] = 0 is causing the increase in object size.

Comment: A slight tangent, but you could use R in conjunction with GRASS. I find I can move the memory load from R to GRASS. See the spgrass6 package.